# Using window.onload/$(window).load to change the visibility of a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a div with the style of `visibility: hidden`, and what I want, is for in the window.load function, I want to set the visibility of it to visible. But what happens in IE8( this works fine in Chrome ), in my actual site a dialog shows up saying that there was an error and it now needs to refresh in compatibility mode. With the following test, the second div does not show, and I get an ActiveX control bar show.

```
<html>
<head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() {
                document.getElementById("DivToShow").style.visibility = 'visible';
            }
        </script>

        <div id="MainDiv" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; background-color: red;">
            <div id="DivToShow" style="width: 250px; height: 250px; background-color: blue; visibility: hidden;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there an issue with IE8 trying to change the visibility of a div? If so, what is the work around? And if not, what is my issue here?

Comment: Have you tried adding a doctype to your page?

Comment: <!doctype html> also there's a semicolon missing behind 'hidden'

Comment: Neither of those worked. Doctype or adding the missing semicolon

Comment: Sounds like local issue with your browser, it [should work](http://jsfiddle.net/KhchW/) on all browsers. Maybe you have JavaScript blocked on your IE8 browser, maybe security set to maximum. Bottom line, there's nothing wrong in the code.

Comment: That semi colon was not mandatory...

Comment: @ShadowWizard there does not seem to be any issues with the browser settings at first glance

Comment: You could of course always use jQuery or style.display = 'none' and style.display = 'block'

Comment: I need the spacing, changing the display works, but I need to allow for the spacing to stay the same, which only visibility allows.

Comment: How about ie8 conditional class + opacity = 0?

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112710/css-style-visibility-not-behaving-as-expected) also applies in your case?

Comment: Are you simply opening the html file in IE (URL=C:\*some path*\filename.html)? The ActiveX message is probably IE telling you it has blocked scripts. Click on that bar and authorize the scripts to run.

Comment: If I click that, it does seem to work fine. But only in my text page. I guess there might be something else affecting my actual work

Comment: you're also missing the `<title></title>` in the document. You need this to make the HTML doc valid. Check this: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.2

Comment: Isn't the doctype case-sensitive, so it should be <!DOCTYPE html>?